# Echo respeitando quebra de linha do mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Gostaria de saber como fazer para que o `echo` do PHP respeitasse a quebra de linha de um texto no banco de dados.

Tenho um campo texto no formulário de cadastro assim:

```
<textarea id="descricao" name="descricao" class="input form-control col-lg-10" rows="5" required></textarea>
```

No banco de dados ele fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que no momento do echo `<?php echo $row['descricao']; ?>`, a mesma quebra de linha do BD fosse respeitada na exibição.

Mas esta aparecendo tudo em uma unica linha:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tenta usar a função [**nl2br()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

**Documentação do PHP:**

> nl2br — Insere quebras de linha HTML antes de todas newlines em uma
>   string

Altera para o seguinte:

```
<?php echo nl2br($row['descricao']); ?>
```

Comment: Legal, não conhecia essa função. Eu ia mandar fazer um `str_replace("\n", "<br>\n", $row['descricao'])`.

Comment: Deu certo! só por curiosidade que tive agora. Para exibir somente como texto, sem a interpretação do html, como seria?

Comment: @KaduAmaral sim, é uma opção que também resulta

Comment: @Tiago seria algo do género :  `<?php echo strip_tags($row['descricao']) ?>`

Comment: @13dev Obrigado.